# why is my do while working when it shouldn't?

Tags: c++, boolean, do-while

Why does the boolean `&&` work in this situation? When I type in "yellow" shouldn't it "short circuit" and not check the second condition since the first condition "red" is false?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string color;
    do
    {
        cout << "Pick one of the colors: red, yellow, or blue\n";
        cin >> color;
    }while ((color != "red") && ( color != "yellow") && ( color != "blue"));

    {
        cout << "I like that color too";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use the second pair of parenthesis at all ? It's part of the problem here?

Comment: You just need a small `!` before the whole condition to correct it.

Comment: '_since the first condition "red" is false?_' It actually isn't. That is probably the source of the whole confusion.

Comment: This isn't the issue, but the code has too many parentheses. In this example, you don't need them around simple expressions like `color != "red"`.

Comment: thanks for all your super fast responses! I figured out my misconception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `color` is `"yellow"`, then `(color != "red")` is true. So it checks the next condition, `(color != "yellow")`, which is false. So the condition is false. The third test `(color != "blue")` is not performed, since the expression evaluated to false already, and so its evaluation was short-circuited.

```
(color != "red")            // color == "yellow", so this is true
&& (color != "yellow")      // color == "yellow", so this is false
&& (color != "blue")
```

Comment: thanks, I don't know why i was having trouble with that simple concept.

Answer (score 0):

In `&&` case event if first single condition evaluate to `false` the result will the whole   conditions will be evaluated to `false`.

Try this solution

```
while ((color != "red") || ( color != "yellow") ||( color != "blue"));
```

Comment: It seems that the questioner wanted this code at the first place but it's not an answer to what he is asking ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the confusion lies in your understanding of the condition :

```
color != "red"
```

When you type yellow it is actually true as the color ain't red , it however short-circuits here :

```
color != "yellow"
```

because the condition is false and since the operands to `&&` must all be true it short-circuits.

Comment: In fact it has to do, it will be printed only when the user gets out of the loop, ie. only when he/she chooses red or yellow or blue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to look at the code:

Seeing how the words while and until are opposite, we can rewrite do while(x) as a do until(!x); loop, iterating through the loop until the condition (!x) is true.

Substituting until(!x) for while(x), we get

```
#include <iostream>
#define until(!(x)) while(x)

int main()
{
    string color;
    do
    {
        cout << "Pick one of the colors: red, yellow, or blue\n";
        cin >> color;
     }
    until (!((color != "red") && ( color != "yellow") && ( color != "blue")));

    cout << "I like that color too";
    return 0;

}
```

Using DeMorgan's Theorem, which states that  !((!x[0])&&(!x[1])&&...&&(!x[n])) == x[0] || x[1] || ... || x[n], we can transform the until statement into

```
until(color == "red" || color == "yellow" || color == "blue");
```

Because ORs only short circuit when the condition is true, when you type in "yellow", the first condition goes false and the second condition goes true.  This causes a short circuit which then breaks out of the do while() loop and prints "I like that color too"!

Comment: The syntax should be `repeat{} until()'.

Comment: I am not using formal programming conventions.  I am simply using ad-hoc substitutions to try to clarify the problem.

Comment: You are correct.  I have added a #define to try to help clarify.